# Token from Myethereumwallet to Coinbase

Tags: ether, myetherwallet, coinbase

I want to turn my token from myetherwallet to real cash. How can I do that?

So for example if I send my Civic tokens to Coinbase, will they be automatically converted to Ethereum and I can withdraw the money from Coinbase? Is it ok to do that or it is not possible that way?

If not, what is the most efficient way of turning my tokens to real cash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that CoinBase probably does not support you trading Ethereum tokens on their platform (but I haven't looked recently). They only deal in Bitcoin, Ethereum, and I think Litecoin. This means that you must either find an exchange that does deal in your token of choice (in your case Civic) and go directly to fiat there, or trade the Civic token for Ether, Bitcoin, or Litecoin and convert to fiat on Coinbase.

I won't recommend any particular exchange, but I will say I've used Kraken and Poloniex in the past. I'm sure there are many more.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/civic/trading_exchanges) site says that the only exchanges that list CVC are Bitrex, Liqui, and HitBTC.

Bitrex is the most well known of those, but have had issues working with US based customers, and actually withdrawing funds in fiat currency.

To convert the CVC to fiat currency you need to sign up to one of those exchanges, transfer the coins to an address that they tell you to, and follow their instructions for using their platform.

Sadly one of the issues with all these ICOs is that the tokens are not necessarily liquid.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you're looking to do is exchange the Civic token for ETH on Etherdelta and then send the ETH to Coinbase. Coinbase doesn't currently support anything besides BTC, LTC, and ETH. Sending anything else to Coinbase will result in you losing it.